# SkillProject, creating the complete skill project

Tags: plugins, jquery-plugins, project, code-signing

Hi folks i'm trying to create a skill project completely related to the database the sample is here : http://en.skill-project.org/skills/
How would i create it, any jquery plugin etc, i have valid json data format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Its Done, and quite easy, i have used typeaheadJs and for the data formation i have used json file in the same format.
Its working quite good for adding the selected tags i have used the jquery and some typeahead **events** that are provided in their library file.

Thanks BTW.